# Como determinar el tiempo transcurrido hasta la media noche

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Necesito determinar el tiempo transcurrido hasta la media noche.

Estos cálculos son correctos:

Desde 11:00am Hasta 12:00pm = 01:00

Desde 00:00am Hasta 11:00pm = 11:00

Desde 11:00am Hasta 01:00pm = 02:00

Pero cuando se calcula el siguiente tiempo el resultado no es correcto:

Desde 11:00PM Hasta 00:00AM = -23:00

Desde 11:00PM Hasta 12:00AM = -23:00

Aquí esperaría que sea = 01:00

Eso es lo que realmente se requiere determinar, el tiempo transcurrido hasta la media noche.

Lo estoy realizando de la siguiente manera:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>00:00:00 AM</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>11:00:00 AM</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>12:00:00 PM</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>10:00:00 PM</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>11:00:00 PM</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>00:00:00 AM</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>11:00:00 AM</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>12:00:00 PM</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>01:00:00 PM</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>12:00:00 AM</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>11:00:00 PM</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Y el cálculo lo realizo de la siguiente manera:

```
   Dim horaInicio As DateTime = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text
    Dim horaFin As DateTime = DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text
    Dim diferencia As TimeSpan = horaFin.Subtract(horaInicio)
    TextBox1.Text = diferencia.ToString()
```

Comment: Creo que la pregunta es incorrecta.. quieres calcular la cantidad de horas entre dos momentos?

Comment: gbianchi Sí, eso quiere

Comment: Si quiere eso, hay un grave problema si no declara el dia de los dos momentos, si no todo se asume el mismo dia y ninguna de las dos respuestas tiene sentido..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buenas,
El problema es que te resta horas pero del mismo día. Así se te debe solucionar:

```
Dim horaInicio As DateTime = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text
Dim horaFin As DateTime = DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text

If horaFin < horaInicio Then horaFin = horaFin.AddDays(1)

Dim diferencia As TimeSpan = horaFin.Subtract(horaInicio)
TextBox1.Text = diferencia.ToString()
```

Saludos.

Comment: Esta es una buena solución.. parcial.. que pasa en los primeros casos que mostró? porque si le agrega a todo un día, se le van a romper los primeros casos.

Comment: Si le agrega un día a todo sí se rompe, pero para eso está el **if**, para que no sea a todo

Comment: Tienes razon.. pero la pregunta me genera dudas y por eso me genero dudas tu respuesta.. Estas en lo correcto, pero me gustaria que OP clarifique un poco lo que quiere...

Comment: Funciona correctamente

Answer (score 1):

Cuando declaras una variable de tipo `DateTime` y es inicializada solo con un `String` con la hora ésta se incializará con la fecha `01/01/0001`, lo cual es incorrecto para la media noche, o en general cualquier hora que esté pasada la media noche.

Por ejemplo si deseas obtener la diferencia de horas entre las  8 PM y 6 AM tendrías el mismo problema. El algoritmo que usas te daría `-14:00:00` cuando lo correcto sería `10:00:00`

En general si la horaFin es menor que la hora inicio se asume que se trata del día siguiente por lo que deberías añadirle un día a tu `horaFin`

```
Dim horaInicio As DateTime = "08:00:00 PM"
Dim horaFin As DateTime = "06:00:00 AM"

If horaInicio > horaFin
    horaFin = horaFin.AddDays(1)
End If

Dim diferencia As TimeSpan = horaFin.Subtract(horaInicio)
TextBox1.Text = diferencia.ToString()
```